# How do i pass the params to the zend_navigation which references the other page

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
$pages = array(
       array(
          'label'    => 'Search',
          'title'    => 'Please Search',
          'uri'      => 'Search.php',
          'params'   => array('stcode'=>$stcode)
        ));
```

now the pages array will be passed to the zend_naviagtion

```
 $container = new Zend_Navigation($pages);
 $view->getHelper('navigation')->setContainer($container);
```

I have a couple of items in the pages array which will help me displaying the menu 
when the menu is generated when i click on that search page and 
it is taking me  to the index.php as the code is  written if stcode is not present then 
it will redirect to index.php .Now my problem is how do i pass the stcode to that page

Comment: I am having trouble following the issue. Is this correct - If there is no `stcode` present when you visit Search.php the user is redirected to index.php? What is the issue, where is it that you can't seem to send the `stcode` value to?

Comment: @jakenoble: if there is no "stcode" present than it is redirected  to index.php.but if i pass in this way 
also suchas it will work search.php?stcode=."$stcode"
but my problem How do i pass the Stcode i dont want to pass in the above  way. 
i want to pass it in along the params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean doing it via the ZF Request Object, like so:

```
$this->getRequest()->setParam("stcode", $the_value);
```

Which can then be accessed like so

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam("stcode");

// You can also pass an optional default value
$this->getRequest()->getParam("stcode", "wibble");
```

Or like so

```
// This has no default value and may return an error depending on your configuration
$this->getRequest()->stcode;
```